# Create object with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'd like to create a function similar that would be used this way:

```
const objectCreator = createObject({
  foo: functionFoo,
  bar: functionBar
})

objectCreator(42) // => { foo: functionFoo(42), bar: functionBar(42) }
```

So the idea is to create an object from a set of function applied to a value. Use case is for example to extract different data from a unique object, and put this function in a pipe.

I could create such a function manually, but isn't there already an existing function in Ramda (or similar) for this? I can't figure how it could be named.

Comment: Don't think there's any *single* function in Ramda that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[applySpec](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec) does that:

```
const functionFoo = x => 'Foo: ' + x;
const functionBar = x => 'Bar: ' + x;

const objectCreator = applySpec({
  foo: functionFoo,
  bar: functionBar
});

objectCreator(42); // {"bar": "Bar: 42", "foo": "Foo: 42"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Map does most of what you need, provided you surround it with code to feed the right values in. For example:

```
const createObject = specification => value => R.map(f => f(value), specification);

const objectCreator = createObject({
  foo: val => val * 2,
  bar: val => val + 1,
});

let result = objectCreator(42); // { foo: 84, bar: 43 }
```

Or if you want it to be curried (so you can pass in the specification and the value at the same time, or separately):

```
const createObject = R.curry((specification, value) => R.map(f => f(value), specification))

let result = createObject({
  foo: val => val * 2,
  bar: val => val + 1,
}, 42); // { foo: 84, bar: 43 }
```

---

EDIT:

If the order of the inputs was reversed (ie, value first, specification later), it would be simpler:

```
const createObject = value => R.map(f => f(value))
```

Comment: That will just result in an exception that `f` is not defined.

Comment: That's an elegant solution, thanks! My misunderstanding was the behaviour of Map. In the first place I thought it took an object and returned an array, so I could not figure out how to write such function. However it takes an object and returns an object, preserving the key.

Comment: Now there is `applySpec`, see prefered answer below. Thanks again!